# Link CMake subprojects with one another

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to link projects that are added via `add_subproject` with one another. Suppose i have a project structure like this:

```
(root)
 I--exec
    I--"some source files"
    I--CMakeLists.txt
 I--lib
    I--"some source files"
    I--CMakeLists.txt
 I--CMakeLists.txt
```

Is there some way i can have my root level CMakeLists.txt just sort-of as a workspace file? So it behaves like a `.sln` from Visual Studio?

I tried this, to give you an idea of what i mean:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

add_subdirectory(exec)
add_subdirectory(lib)

target_link_libraries(exec lib)
target_include_directories(exec lib/include)
```

Obviously, it threw a config error at the second last line, stating that i cannot do that because exec is not built by this file (the current `CMakeLists.txt`?). Is there some way to achive what i want to do?

Comment: ***Obviously, it threw a config error at the second last line*** It's not obvious to me why this failed. I do this all the time. Although these days I have removed the project() from the non root CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: ***cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)*** Do you really need to support back to 2.8?

Comment: @drescherjm no i dont, i just put in some arbitrary version number out of memory :P i can add the full log when executing above file. Can you perhaps try a similar scenario and tell me your results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For CMake >= 2.8.10, the usage of `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories` is incorrect.

They should specify the target SYSTEM|BEFORE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE|PRIVATE; prefixed by LINK_ on `target_link_libraries`.

As a side-note, just for clear dependency management (IMHO):

In your root CMakeLists.txt there should be no `target_link_libraries` nor `target_include_directories`, they should be in the subproject. So your root CMakeLists, for example, should be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(exec)
```

In your exec/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable (exec main.cpp)

target_link_libraries (exec LINK_PUBLIC lib)
target_include_directories (exec PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib)
```

In your lib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library (lib libmain.cpp)

target_include_directories (lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I use the `add_subdirectory` for the library before the executable.

Comment: Thank you, i shall try this immediately :3. I wasnt aware that the two subprojects even know of each other here, i expected CMake to not know about `lib` when calling `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Forgot to explain why it was wrong. In CMake 2.8.10, a new parameter to target_link_libraries and target_include_directories was added.

Comment: Yes, CMake doesn't generate the project files on-the-fly. It has full dependency checking (internally it generates a graph in order to parallelize the build - you can't compile a project if another that it depends on isn't compiled yet). So that's why I don't think that the add_subdirectories order won't affect the build process.